# Fetch files from outside of SvelteKit project directory

Tags: django, rest, svelte, sveltekit

I'm fetching data, including media file links, from a Django API.
Project structure as follows:

```
-backend (Django)
   -core
      -media
-frontend (SvelteKit)
   -src
   -lib
   -node_modules
```

Both apps are running on different ports and I can't figure out how to access the files inside of *`backend/core/media`* from SvelteKit after fetching the link.
The media link I'm receiving by my API would be something like this:
*`/media/images/user1/image.jpg`*

Comment: `/media/images/user1/image.jpg` is served by your backend you just have to add your backed url before that so it will display in your UI eg. `https://myapi.com/media/images/user1/image.jpg`

Comment: Alright, thank you! I constructed a base url by doing `let url = "http://" + window.location.hostname + ":port/media/" + media_link;`